# How to implement onbeforeunload behavior for a div?

Tags: javascript

I posted recently regarding onbeforeunload implementation. Its working now but that only solved half of the problem. My application has lot of tabs and I want to throw this same confirmation to user if he clicks on a new tab without saving changes. all the tabs are div elements. How do you implement something of this sort?
Sample tab structure is attached, where every tab loads a new page.[image]

Comment: What's happening on the tabs? Would need to understand that before knowing how state could be captured for them - then I would probably assign click handlers for all the tabs that check the state being set for any given tab.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd have to use a library to listen for the destruction of a specific element. I know YUI has a 'destroy' event for nodes, and I don't use jquery but I'd bet that they have something similar.

Comment: as user156629 suggested, I'd trap any unsaved change somewhere, and if there are some, clicking to __load__ a new tab would trigger the confirmation.

Comment: @ user156629, Every Tab is a different page.

Comment: @Kraz, I have a global variable flag which is set everytime an onChange event occurs on the form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would help you. You need to add the clickHandler to each tab click event.

```
var dirty = false;

function clickHandler(){
     if (dirty && confirm('you are leaving the tab, wanna stay and save?')){
         return false; //prevent default
     }
     else {
         dirty = false;
         //trigger your tab load
     }
}
```